# Email before download error php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, download

I'm having issues with email before download error it say

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /wp-content/plugins/email-before-download/includes/class-email-before-download-db.php on line 56`

How do I fix this issues?

[image]

Comment: the function count in php accepts a countable parameter like an array or object. Look on line 56 the parameter for count is maybe a string like count($param). You can check for array before the count function to prevent errors

Comment: @MikeAron see this `public function item_exists($data) { //check if item exists and if it needs updated $query = $this->db->get_row("SELECT * FROM $this->item_table WHERE download_id = '" . $data['download_id'] . "'"); if (count($query) > 0) { if ($query->file != $data['file']) { $this->db->update($this->item_table, array('file' => $data['file']), array('id' => $query->id) ); } if ($query->title != $data['title']) { $this->db->update($this->item_table, array('title' => $data['title']), array('id' => $query->id) ); } return $query->id; } return false; }` How do I fix this?

Comment: Please place your **additional code in your post** and not as a comment.

Comment: You say this is a WP plugin. The code is wrong from Top to end. Database fuctions are not WP norm. So i can not help you i dont know what $this->db-get_row will return. But to only prevent the error you can replace count($query) with is_array($query) && count($query)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the error. Replace

```
 if (count($query) > 0) {
```

with

```
 if (is_array($query) && count($query) > 0) {
```

Comment: thanks it works but when i click donwload button, fill contact form 7 submit it but there is no download link after submit

Comment: as i said i dont know what the function is it need to be deeper analyzed. The code above is only to prevent the error.